# Ember Hello Word - Test Error in http://localhost:4200/tests but not in command line

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, ember.js

I am trying to build a hello world Ember.js app by following [this tutorial](https://dockyard.com/blog/2014/05/09/building-an-ember-app-with-rails-part-3)...I have gotten to the part where I test the link to an About page.

My setup is:

```
QUnit 1.18.0; Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
Ember version: 1.13.8
node: 0.12.7
npm: 2.13.4
os: darwin x64
```

My `router.js` is:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('about');
});

export default Router;
```

My `application.hbs` is:

```
<h2 id="title">Welcome to Boston Ember</h2>

{{link-to 'About' 'about'}}

{{outlet}}
```

My `about.hbs` is:

```
<h3>About</h3>

<p>Boston Ember is the monthly meetup where awesome people get together
```

to do awesome Ember related things!

My `about-page-test.js` is:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import startApp from 'bostonember/tests/helpers/start-app';

var App;

module('Integration - About Page', {
  beforeEach: function() {
    App = startApp();
  },
  afterEach: function() {
    Ember.run(App, 'destroy');
  }
});

test('Should navigate to the About page', function() {
  visit('/').then(function(assert) {
    click("a:contains('About')").then(function(assert) {
      assert.equal(find('h3').text(), 'About');
    });
  });
});
```

The page functions as it should and the command line does not return any errors:

```
file changed templates/application.hbs

Build successful - 691ms.
```

But when I go to `http://localhost:4200/tests` I see a bunch of errors...

```
Integration - About Page: Should navigate to the About page (1, 0, 1)Rerun210 ms
TypeError: Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined@ 190 ms
Expected:   true
Result:     false
Diff:   trufalse
Source:     
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:4578:13
    at exports.default._emberTestingAdaptersAdapter.default.extend.exception (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:52460:34)
    at onerrorDefault (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:43162:24)
    at Object.exports.default.trigger (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:67346:11)
    at Promise._onerror (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:68312:22)
    at publishRejection (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:66619:15)

JSHint - integration: integration/about-page-test.js should pass jshint (1, 0, 1)Rerun1 ms
integration/about-page-test.js should pass jshint.
integration/about-page-test.js: line 6, col 1, 'module' is not defined.
integration/about-page-test.js: line 15, col 1, 'test' is not defined.
integration/about-page-test.js: line 16, col 28, 'assert' is defined but never used.

3 errors@ 0 ms
Expected:   true
Result:     false
Diff:   trufalse
Source:     
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4200/assets/bostonember.js:337:12)
    at Object.Test.run (http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:3566:28)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:3695:11
    at process (http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:3254:24)
    at begin (http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:3299:2)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:3315:4
```

I have tried using some different variations of `this.route('about');` although I think this is fine, since the functionality works. I have also tried some different things in the test, but nothing gets rid of the browser error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems as though I had the `assert`s in the wrong place. The following passed:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import startApp from '../helpers/start-app';

var App;

module('Integration - About Page', {
  beforeEach: function() {
    App = startApp();
  },
  afterEach: function() {
    Ember.run(App, 'destroy');
  }
});

test('Should click About link', function(assert) {
  visit('/').then(function() {
    click("a:contains('About')").then(function() {
      assert.equal(find('h3').text(), 'About');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This code is pretty much identical to the one you first posted, only difference is that you have "import { module, test } from 'qunit';" ?

Comment: The issue was in the placements of the assert's. Very slight difference, but it is what caused one of the errors above. I am not saying that your solution was bad. Just providing the full solution because testing has changed slightly in recent version updates to ember.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include qUnit for assertions and startApp for ember testing helpers.

```
import Ember from "ember";
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import startApp from '../helpers/start-app';
```

Module can be defined for models.

```
import { test, moduleForModel } from 'ember-qunit';


moduleForModel('recipe/recipe', 'Unit | Models | Recipe |', {
    needs: ['model:recipe/recipe', 'model:recipe/category', 'model:filerepository/file']
});
```

where

> this.subject()

references to the imported module.

Examples: http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#testing

Comment: I added the imports but am still getting the same errors. I was also missing phantonJS which I was missing. Still errors.